# Shall I clear a vector of unique_ptr in destructor in c++11 even if valgrind doesn't show memory leak

Tags: c++, c++11, memory-leaks, valgrind, smart-pointers

Giving the `Holder` class below:

```
    class Holder {
        string  name;
        std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Object>> objects;
    public:
        Holder(string name): name(name){
        }   

        ~Holder(){};
        Holder & operator=(const Holder & holder) = delete;  

    vector<unique_ptr<Object>> const& Holder::getContent()const{
        return this->objects;
    }

    void Holder::add(unique_ptr<Object> objPtr){
       this->objects.push_back(move(objPtr));
    }


    };
```

If I am calling my Holder object in the method below:

```
void HolderTest::addObject(){
    Holder *holder = new Holder("bag");
    holder->add(unique_ptr<Object>(new Object("test")));
    vector<unique_ptr<Object>> const& objects = holder->getContent();
    const std::string name = objects[0].get()->name();
    CPPUNIT_ASSERT_EQUAL((string)"test", name);
    delete holder;
}
```

My question is: should I call my vector of unique_ptr's clear method in the Holder destructor to avoid memory leak like below?

```
~Holder(){
  this->objects.clear();
};
```

My other question can I still use "Valgrind Tools Integration" version  3.0.0.201502180018 for finding memory leaks in a c++11 application or it is not able to find memory leak in c++11 programs?

Comment: Why is your `Holder` allocated dynamically, risking it is leaked if you unexpectedly leave the function? That said, your question boils down to the question whether the destructor of a `vector<unique_ptr<T>>` will release what it references. To that, consider what the call of `clear()` does, which is almost the same. In summary, destructors are an important part of C++, allowing you to automate resource management, you can rely on this.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt My Holder is allocated dynamically because I could not use assignment operator when I have a vector of unique_ptr. Writing this code Holder holder =  Holder("bag"); cause problem because unique_ptr doesn't have copy constructor. Because of this I deleted my assignment operator inside holder Holder & operator=(const Holder & holder) = delete;  Is there any other way to do this? I know that I can put my holder in unique_ptr as well. But I am asking if there is a way to create holder by value.

Comment: The correct way is to write `Holder holder("bag");`, simple as that. If you knew you could put it into a `unique_ptr`, why didn't you? Doing these things consequently is an important part of C++ programming.

Comment: Ah thank you @UlrichEckhardt. When you are coming from Java world to c++ world you are always confused with syntax.

Comment: A good rule of thumb in C++11 is that if you're writing a destructor or copy/move operator, you're probably doing something wrong. Google for "C++ the rule of zero".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not have technically any memory leak. When you delete your holder, all elements in the `vector` are destroyed (because the destructor of Holder already clears the vector), and the destructor of unique_ptr actually release the memory allocated for added objects.

What it seems strange to me is that probably for your situation the most simple solution is using

```
std::vector< Object> objects;
objects.emplace_back("test");
```

wich is more efficient and simpler to read.

EDIT: 2nd part of the question, Valgrind may have a false positive (warn about a leak when you have no leak), but I never heard of Valgrind reporting a false negative (signaling no leak at all when you have a leak).

EDIT2:

```
#include <utility>  // std::forward
#include <vector>

//...

template< typename... Args>
void Holder::add( Args&&... args){
   objects.emplace_back( std::forward< Args>(args)...);
}
```

usage:

```
holder.add("Test");
```

Comment: Do you mean inside add function shall I use emplace back instead of push_back?or inside the test function? Inside test function I want to call add to test add function. Object has more parameter than name. Can I emplace back Object? something like this void Holder::add(Object object){
       this->objects.emplace_back(object);
    }

Comment: @Govan No, you can't because that's not how [`emplace_back`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back) works. Indeed, `emplace_back` emplaces a _new_ element; `push_back`, instead, copies/moves an existing one. DarioOO shows how it may be used in your case.

Comment: I added a possible implementation for your function ... see the edit (#2) ;)

Comment: If we are keeping OP's current design (`vector<unique_ptr<>>`), then `emplace_back` is the wrong way to go.

Answer (score 7):

You do not have to call `clear` manually. The destructor of `std::vector<T>` will call destructors of `std::unique_ptr<T>` automatically.

The major advantage of smart pointers over built-in pointers is that you don't have to deal with manual clean-up.